# Probability of getting same element

Tags: probability

Let $A = \{1,\ldots,100\}$. We choose a uniform random element $x$ in $A$ and independently choose a uniform random element $y$ in $A$. What is the probability that $x = y$?

This is how I solve this problem - I just subtract probability of $x$ is not equal to $y$ from $1$.

So

$$1 - \frac{100}{100} \cdot \frac{99}{100} = \frac{1}{100}$$

$\frac{100}{100}$ is because $x$ can be any element but for $y$, it can be any but element $x$.

Am I using the right logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is good. The reasoning is correct, and well explained.  One can use the same logic in a somewhat easier way.

**Whatever** first element is chosen, the probability the second  **matches** it is $\frac{1}{100}$. There is no need to first evaluate the probability of  "doesn't match" and then subtract from $1$.

We can also do the problem less efficiently, by noting that there are $100^2$ ordered pairs of (first choice, second choice), and all of these are equally likely. The number of ordered pairs in which both entries are the same is $100$, so our probability is $\frac{100}{100^2}$.